# How to serialze a map in RestyGWT

Tags: gwt, resty-gwt

I want to send a `Map<String,Object>` to a server using RestyGWT.  However, when I serialize a map in the request it adds extra quote escapes around the string keys.

So,

```
map.put("hello",123);
service.sendRequest(map,callback);
```

results in JSON being sent of

```
{"\"hello\"":123}
```

instead of the desired result

```
{"hello":123}
```

Here is the RestyGWT interface:

```
@POST
@Path("/data")
public void setRequest(Map<String, Object> map, JsonCallback callback);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour was a bug.  It has been fixed in the latest source version, so v1.4 onwards should not see this issue.